# Programmatically added UIImageView won't show up

Tags: iphone, object, uiview

I've been trying for an hour and nothing I do can seem to make this show the image:

```
UIImageView*logo=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"logo.png"]];
logo.frame=pos; // a CGRect I previously created
self.taskbarlogo=logo;
[logo release];
[self.popupwindow addSubview:self.taskbarlogo];
```

logo.png is definitely there in the project

this is the last subview added to `self.popupwindow` so it should be on top

the `hidden` property is never handled anywhere so it should be visible

The following `NSLog` confirms the placement of the UIImageView's frame:

```
NSLog(@"frame: %f %f %f %f",self.taskbarlogo.frame.origin.x,self.taskbarlogo.frame.origin.y, self.taskbarlogo.frame.size.width, self.taskbarlogo.frame.size.height);
```

It reports:

```
frame: 20.000000 20.000000 96.000000 33.000000
```

this is certainly onscreen, or certainly should be as my superview's frame is much larger than this

what am I missing?! there is no crash, no errors, just.... no image.

Comment: Does the popupwindow show up on the screen properly?  What's it's frame?

Comment: Is the taskbarlogo property set to retain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the file inspector (one of the right side tabs) under Target Membership and make sure the image belongs to all targets where the resource is desired.  Also call bringSubviewToFront to be sure it's on top.

Comment: beautiful. i learned something about targets, and solved the issue. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

does it happen in iDevice AND in simulator?

try to delete the folder "build" in you project folder.

control that your file is checked for export as resource in xcode.

try menu:build:clean (and clean all target)